# How can get VS Code Intellisense to recognize JSDoc annotations?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc, javascript-intellisense

How should I document the below code so that it would work with vscode Intellisense to get all the methods to show?

I have tried various combination of `@class`, `@typedef` above `TMCharacter.Character` but it didn't work like I expected it to. Intellisense still recognize my_char as type `any`.

```js
/** @namespace */
var TMCharacter = {}

TMCharacter.Character = cc.Sprite.extend({
    ctor: function(spritename){
        cc.Sprite.prototype.ctor.call(this, spritename);
        this.setupCharacter();
    },

    onEnter: function(){
        this._super();
    },

    /**
     * Setup the components for the characters
     * @method
     */
    setupCharacter: function(){
       // do stuff
    }
});
/** @type {TMCharacter.Character} */
var my_char = new TMCharacter.Character(sprite)
```